# How to maintain history in postgresql

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, react-hooks, local-storage

I have updated query

`update table set date = '2021-03-02' where id=1`

Now I need to revert back previously stored data on clicking of **Quit button** in UI.
So whatever changes did should revert back.

How we can do this by storing data as a history, is anyone have an idea please help me to proceed.

Comment: Not easy. You'd have to save a log of all actions you did and the previous state.

Comment: This is going to depend on the UI code you are using. Also I'm not sure `Quit` is really the correct term for what you are doing. To me it just says I'm done, not that I want to revert back to a previous state. You may want to make that more explicit.

Comment: I've done something like this before. But it is a lot more work. You can create a new table called `mytable_old` or `mytable_history`. Then you'll have to create a trigger (and possibly a trigger stored procedure?) that automatically saves the old record to the history table. And then if you rollback, you'll need some code that copies the data from the history table to the live table. You can optionally delete the moved line in the history table.

Comment: Your description indicates you are either trying to run a "What If" scenario which is never saved, or allow user to make changes but then to not save them. As indicated the "capture and restore" you envision involves a lot of work.The easiest may be not attempting it, but just *not committing* automatically but; control commit in the app.  For either make sure any AUTO COMMIT is turned off, then for the former issue a *rollback*, for the latter offer 2 options `Quit and Discard` which issues *rollback* and `Quit and Save` which issues *commit*.